# Windows 10 custom context menu doesn't work

Tags: windows-10

I want to right click on any file and make a program(I write) appear there.
Ideally when I right click on the item it would feed the file name to my program.

I've edited the registry at the location:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT -> * -> shellex -> ContextMenuHandlers
```

There I've created a new directory "GetBookScore"
Then I created a new Key, with Default name and `Value("C:\myprogram.exe") %1`

This doesn't work. My program doesn't appear in the context menu when I click on any file.

Any hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a .reg file with the following contents.
Change the program name and path from Wordpad to your desired program.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; add_Open_with_wordpad_to_context_menu.reg
; displays when you right-click any file
; You must have the "\ before the path
; Make sure folder name and program name match command path
; and the path must contain double \\
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with Wordpad]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with Wordpad\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\windows nt\\accessories\\wordpad.exe\" \"%1\""
```